# How to force version of dependence library in Composer

Tags: php, composer-php, version, libraries

I have a composer.json which contains library **nette/nette** which has dependence to other library **nette/deprecated** and this nested library has a bug in newer version. So I need to force Composer to load previous version of nested library nette/deprecated. The problem is that the main library nette/nette need s to be of version "nette/nette": "**~2.4.0**" but all the 2.4 and also 2.5 versions depends on the buggy nette/deprecated library. How to force Composer to load exactly required version of nested nette/deprecated library? It seems it is not possible or I am not enough educated in Composer features. 
Thanks.

Comment: Did you try to do `composer remove nette/nette` and after that a `composer require nette/nette ~2.4.0` again?

Comment: Problem is not in nette/nette version ~2.4.0. Problem is in nette/deprecated version.

Comment: It seems I found a solution. If nette/deprecated is explicitly set in top level composer.json Composer loads this version of library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know that a dependency has a bug or interferes with something in your code you can mark it as conflicting in your composer.json.

```
{
    "...",
    "require": {
        "..."
    },
    "conflict": {
        "nette/deprecated": ">2.4.0,<3.0.0"
    }
}
```

This will exclude everything after `2.4.0` and smaller than `3.0.0`, but you can change the value to whatever you need it to be. This way you can communicate clearly, that there are certain versions that are off limits without explicitly declaring this as a root dependency.

See also: https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#conflict